# Load different web page if using an iPhone vs Android

Tags: html

i want iphone users who go to my website be allowed to, but if an android user goes to the same page, I want it to load a different page, like a desktop page.
Is it possible to add a code that will differentiate the two?

Thanks

Comment: try navigator.userAgent

Answer (score 1):

if that doesn't work try this PHP.

```
 if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/iphone');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
    if(!/(iphone|ipod)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      //code for iphone or ipod
    }

    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android ")>=0){
    //for android
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a way (I am not sure if is this the best way to do that or not). Called **User Agent**.

### Android Detection

**JavaScript**

Searching the user agent string for "Android" is the quickest method:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Redirect to Android-site?
    window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

**PHP**

Again, we'll use PHP's strstr function to search for Android in the user agent:

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
    header('Location: http://android.davidwalsh.name');
    exit();
}
```

**.htaccess**

We can even use .htaccess directives to detect and react to Android devices!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Android.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://android.davidwalsh.name [R=301]
```

---

### iPhone and iPad detection

**JavaScript**

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
     if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) window.location = "http://m.espn.go.com/wireless/?iphone&i=COMR";
}
```

**PHP**

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/iphone');
    exit();
}
```

Source: http://davidwalsh.name/